# Confused about using the very same HTTPContextAccessor instance through the entire ASP.NET Core 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, httpcontext

I've read about configuring `IHttpContextAccessor` as `services.AddSingleton` scope, but I also read about it is working "async local", and I am also aware of the sophisticated working of async in ASP.Net, I mean for example if a controller action method is `async`, and it `await` for an `async` call, then it may continue with an other thread, but magically some thread bound things with maintained (like `HttpContext`)

My concrete use case: I have to inject a `MyConverter` class to my EF Core `DbContext` which uses it in `OnModelCreating`. However this model is cached by the `DbContext`, so any subsequent request, even it will have a brand new instance of `DbContext` will use this very same model so the very same `MyConverter` instance. (even it has configured `services.AddTransient`). This `MyConverter` has a constructor and an injected `IHttpContextAccessor`, so based on the very similar reasons, it effectively will be also a singleton for all `DbContext/MyConverter` usages.

**Question**

This particular `HttpContextAccessor` instance which is created in the very first request will serve all the subsequent requests in the Web app lifecycle. Will it work correctly? Is there any (concurrency) trap here?

(Do I suppose correctly that it **does not really matter** if we use a single or multiple `HttpContextAccessor` instances, because *its implementation of getting `HttpContext`* will use the correct way including async local thread switch traps etc to return with the correct `HttpContext`?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer: register as `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` and then you can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` wherever you want and it'll work as long as you're using it in the request's execution context. For instance you can't read HTTP request headers for code that was not initiated by a HTTP request.

---

You're right that the `IHttpContextAccessor` should be registered as a singleton. Instead of doing it yourself, the [recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components) is to use `AddHttpContextAccessor()` extension method. See [source code here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.5/src/Http/Http/src/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27). It internally registers an `HttpContextAccessor` as a singleton.

The code for `HttpContextAccessor` [can be found here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.5/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs), which I'm also pasting below:

```cs
public class HttpContextAccessor : IHttpContextAccessor
{
    private static AsyncLocal<HttpContextHolder> _httpContextCurrent = new AsyncLocal<HttpContextHolder>();

    public HttpContext HttpContext
    {
        get
        {
            return  _httpContextCurrent.Value?.Context;
        }
        set
        {
            var holder = _httpContextCurrent.Value;
            if (holder != null)
            {
                // Clear current HttpContext trapped in the AsyncLocals, as its done.
                holder.Context = null;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                // Use an object indirection to hold the HttpContext in the AsyncLocal,
                // so it can be cleared in all ExecutionContexts when its cleared.
                _httpContextCurrent.Value = new HttpContextHolder { Context = value };
            }
        }
    }

    private class HttpContextHolder
    {
        public HttpContext Context;
    }
}
```

Since the `HttpContext` getter property returns from an async local field, you always get the `HttpContext` local to the execution context.

The `HttpContext` field is set in `HttpContextFactory.Create()` only if `IHttpContextAccessor` was registered with the DI. [Source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.5/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextFactory.cs#L39-L42).

And `HttpContextFactory.Create()` is invoked from `[HostingApplication](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.5/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/HostingApplication.cs)` where the context is setup.

Comment: I have a problem with the IHttpContextAccessor , in some situations using the same browser and accessing at the same time, HttpContext.Session.Id returns differents Id. Some Idea why?

Comment: @CryingFreeman did you enable sessions? Ideally you'd want to avoid using sessions, but if you want sessions to match, you'll need to enable them.

Comment: I have enabled services.AddSession , does this need to be after or before services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

Comment: @CryingFreeman that doesn't matter. Have you also done UseSession when configuring the pipeline?

Comment: yes I have  app.UseSession();, my sessions works fine , my problem is that accessing at the same time in the same browser the accessor.HttpContext.Session.Id is different

Comment: @CryingFreeman I see I'll need to check later on. Do post a question, someone might answer meanwhile.

Comment: @galdin I am using AddHttpContextAccessor() extension method, but still IHttpContextAccessor gets reset for every new request. Any idea why?

Comment: @Sunny what do you mean by `IHttpContentAccessor` gets reset? `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` _will_ be different for each request, like I explained in the answer.

Comment: @galdin Yes, that I understood. But I am confused that how even if AddHttpContextAccessor() extension is registering IHttpContextAccessor as a singleton then also, by using AsyncLocal HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext will be different for each request?

Comment: @Sunny yes. Think of `IHttpContextAccessor` (singleton) as a way of making it possible to make request specific information (scoped -- not really scoped, but you can think of it as such) accessible via DI.